# Redirection does not seem to be working and shows Forbidden error message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have added a link to my webpage like this:

```
<a alt="English" href="{{ route('english.version') }}">En</a>
```

And here is the route `english.version`:

```
Route::get('/en', function () {
    redirect(url('https://websitename.com/landing'));
})->name('english.version');
```

But now whenever I click on the link **En**, I get this error:

> **Forbidden** You don't have permission to access this resource.

So the question is, how can I be able to show `/en` link, and when users clicked on it, it redirect another url which is `https://websitename.com/landing` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should return from closure then it will redirect you to target.

```
Route::get('/en', function () {
    return redirect(url('https://websitename.com/landing'));
})->name('english.version');
```

That's the only issue right now.
Please try it and let me know.
Thanks